# Installing open source web-based software?

Tags: web-services, compilation, open-source, installation, centos

new to working with Web Servers and despite my tedious Googling, I think I am missing some of the most general (obvious?) questions regarding how to install an open source web-based program.

I have a dedicated server running CentOS 6, 32GB of RAM, etc........ I used a SSH Client to install the prerequisites of PandoraFMS. Everything installed finE.

Now what, just upload all the open-source files onto the web server?? That's the part I am not understanding about the general process of installing an open source program using build files, do I just UPLOAD it all to my server, or am I missing something???

Answer (score 0):

You use Yum from the command line.  Here is a link to the documentation http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html.  If you really want a linux box that is easy to use I recommend Ubuntu.  Good Luck